# WinstonJS integrate timestamp into log file name for FileTransport

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am using `winstonjs 3.0.0` for generating log files, I am currently using File transport for generating log files.

```
const file = new winston.trasnports.File({
...
filename: 'xxx.log',
maxSize: 1024
...
})
```

Using the code below, I get log files with names like `'xxx.log', 'xxx1.log'`.
I want to get file name with the date information when the file is created: `'YYYY-MM-DD-xxx.log'`. I considered `'winston-daily-rotate-file'`, but I do not want the log rotate within time.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append date at the beginning of the filename like this:

```
let mydate = new Date();
let newFilename = mydate.getFullYear() + "-" + mydate.getMonth() + "-" + mydate.getDate() + "-" + "xxx.log";
const file = new winston.trasnports.File({
...
filename: newFilename,
maxSize: 1024
...
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How silly me, I should have thought about this solution. I optimised your code a bit via momentjs `const file = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MMM-DD') + '-' + 'xxx.log'; ... `

Comment: you don't need to say new Date(). Moment will give you the date. It's redundant in this case. However with the newest version of Winston this doesn't work at all. No files created and no errors.

Comment: @Urasquirrel, I didn't use the moment module while answering the question. It was a simple js snippet and also it was posted a year back

Comment: this solution is not dynamic. if it only gets instantiated once, then all logs will go into the same file forever.